# Is it possible to upgrade 2012 low res glossy to high res glossy screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, resolution

I know you can switch the screen assembly from high-resolution matte to high resolution glossy, but can you go from low-resolution glossy to high resolution?

Specifically, if I get a 15" 2012 MBP and take it to an Apple Authorized Service Provider (AASP), can they upgrade a low-resolution glossy to high-resolution (non retina) glossy screen?

I purchased a 2012 MBP with the anti-glare, but I'd really rather have the glossy. So, it seems silly to pay more for a higher resolution screen and then just turn around and get it switched over at an AASP when I could just return the one I purchased and wait for one like I have but with a lower resolution screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it would be possible. 
But apple doesn't offer an upgrade price, so you're only option is buying the screen for the rather high "stock" price. 
Selling yours on ebay and getting a model you want is probably cheaper

Comment: Buying the screen for the rather high stock price is a given as I would have to do that going from high-res matte to high-res glossy or low-res glossy to high-res glossy; so, either way I wind up paying for the high-res glossy screen separately. 

It's just that I've heard conflicting information on the feasibility doing this. I've read that it is possible as well as impossible. So, I was looking for someone who knew for a fact if it was possible or impossible.

Comment: It is possible. The logic boards in these macbooks are the same, regardless of the display configuration

Comment: That's good. I read somewhere else where someone said that the wires coming off of the board are different for the high res and low res monitors. I guess I'll just return this one and just hold out until a 2012 refurb comes out like mine but with the low res monitor.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's apparently not possible:

https://de.ifixit.com/Answers/View/124673/Upgrading+Low+Res+LCD+to+High+Res+compatibility

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.